# Как из addListener получить доступ к хозяину?

Tags: java, android

доступ к объекту-хозяину через `this`?

```
obj[i].addListener(new InputListener(){
    public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        obj/this - ?
        ...
        return true;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, что так (возможно, `int` надо заменить на `Integer`):

```
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
  final int j = i;

  obj[j].addListener(new InputListener(){
    public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
      ... obj[j] ...
      return true;
    };
});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете обращаться к объекту ровно также, как и вне методов (анонимного) класса, просто по имени, но при этом переменная должна быть объявлена с модификатором `final`.

PS. В данном случае, `this` – это инстанс анонимного класса, реализующего интерфейс `InputListener`, поэтому он тут не в тему совсем.

Comment: а как быть если у меня массив `obj`, как обратиться к членам класса из такого положения?  `obj[i].addListener(new InputListener(){ ..`

Comment: @ravend, Так же.

Comment: можно пример? например у `obj` есть свойство `value` как из `obj[i].addListener(new InputListener(){ ..` обратиться к `value` этого элемента массива?

Comment: @ravend, `obj[i].value`, если поле доступно напрямую извне и через геттер, если поле приватное.

Comment: так при вызове `InputListener` индекс `i` будет иметь другое значение. в этом та как раз и вопрос

Comment: @ravend, Если используете Android Studio, то можно просто нажать `Alt` + `Enter` и получите ровно то, что написали в соседнем ответе (если Вас устраивает такой вариант). Пока я не очень понимаю, что Вы хотите сделать.